# How to get the time created for a ListItem programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm building a webpart for SharePoint 2010 in ASP.NET and I would like to know how to get the time in which a ListItem was created at.

With an `SPFile` I can simply do `file.TimeCreated`, but `ListItem` doesn't have that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListItems store the created and modified datetimes as columns.  You can access the created time like so:

```
DateTime created = (DateTime)myListItem["Created"];
```